# How to add Timer after clicking a button to get response

Tags: android

If i click button it prints response on the screen.but what i want is for every response it should print corresponding time also.and then it should show difference between time if we click button multiple time.it should print the difference between last and 2nd last response time.i tried this till now.

```
package com.example.volleydemo;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button Click;
    TextView responseText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        responseText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button) {
            RequestQueue requestQueue;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                    null, response -> {
                try {
                    responseText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d(TAG, "the response is" + response.getString("title"));
                    responseText.setText(" ID" + response.getString("id") + "\n Title-" +
                            response.getString("title") + "\n Completed-" +
                            response.getString("completed") + "\n User ID"
                            + response.getString("userId") + "\n");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Xml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have added code below with timestamp

Comment: ok let me try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

**XML File-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Class File-**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button Click;
    TextView responseText, timerText, timeLast;
    int clickCount = 0;
    Date endTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Click.setOnClickListener(this);
        responseText = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        timerText = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        timeLast = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button) {
            timerText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timeLast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss aa");
            String differenceTime = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
            timeLast.setText("Current API call Time : " + differenceTime);
            String diff = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(currentTime.getTime(), endTime.getTime(),
                    DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS).toString();

            String lastSeen = dateFormat.format(endTime);
            timerText.setText("Last call was done at : " + lastSeen +
                    "\nLast API Call was done before : " + diff + " ago");
            endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }

        int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 200);

        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + randomInt,
                null, response -> {
            try {

               /* new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Click.setEnabled(false);
                        Click.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        Click.setEnabled(true);
                        Click.setText("Click");
                    }
                }.start();*/

                responseText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "the response is" + response.getString("title"));

                responseText.setText(" ID" + response.getString("id") + "\n Title-" +
                        response.getString("title") + "\n Completed-" +
                        response.getString("completed") + "\n User ID"
                        + response.getString("userId") + "\n");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> Log.d("myapp", "something went wrong"));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```